# Recognizeability of PFTM

Tags: fl.formal-languages

I encountered this problem here: [https://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs172/ps05.pdf](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Etrevisan/cs172/ps05.pdf)

Consider the language
$$PFTM := \{\langle M \rangle : \text{$M$ is a Turing machine and $L(M)$ is prefix free} \}$$

where L(M) is the set of strings accepted by M.

(a) Prove that PFTM is undecidable.
(b) Is PFTM recognizable?
(c) Is the complement of PFTM recognizable?

I think I have a proof for a, but I'm unsure about how to go about b and c. I tried a mapping reduction from $A_{TM}$ to both but couldn't really figure it out.

Comment: This is not a research-level question, and should have been asked at https://cs.stackexchange.com rather than here. Anyway, the answer immediately follows from Rice and Rice–Shapiro theorems.

Comment: Actually, forget about Rice–Shapiro. Rice's theorem is enough if you solve (c) first. Can you think of a way how to witness that $L(M)$ is *not* prefix-free?

Comment: Yes I believe if I take $\overline{PFTM}$, I think the reduction is clearer that this will be recognizable from $A_{TM}$, meaning that $PFTM$ is itself not recognizable.